# DIV overflows its container

Tags: css

I have 4 divs, `outer`, `inner`, `title`, and `content`. I want to place `inner` div inside the outer, and `title` and `content` - inside the `inner` div, one on top of the other. I positioned outer and inner divs relative and the other 2 - absolute.

`inner` div fits right inside thew `outer`, but `title` and `content` overflow the `inner` div.

How can I fix my CSS here?

```css
#outer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#inner .title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#inner .content {
  padding: 2em 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFF;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this might be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY (But why can't you just change the html structure?) - I didn't DV BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#outer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
padding: 0 5px;
}

#inner .title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#inner .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to prevent the `title` and `content` from overflow each other just assign a `relative` position to them and assign the `absolute` position to its parent . just like that

```
#outer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#inner {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

#inner .title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

#inner .content {
  padding: 2em 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFF;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried that but title and content still overflow inner div

Comment: try to assign position:relative to them all.

Comment: still overflows